# Qué es un fichero serializado

Tags: java, archivo, serialización, interface

estamos trabajando en clase con ficheros, pero hay un concepto que no entiendo: ***fichero serializable***. 
¿Qué es exactamente? Sé que hay que implementar la interfaz **Serializable**,
pero no termino de entender para qué sirven.

Comment: Perdona que me salga del tema, pero... Si tienes una duda sobre algo que estáis dando en clase ¿por qué no preguntas a tu profesor/a? Sabe mejor hasta dónde habéis dado y de qué forma puede explicarlo para que lo entendáis mejor

Comment: @Rabegi Porque ni los apuntes ni la profesora tienen idea. Por eso pregunto por aquí.

Comment: A groso modo un fichero serializable es un fichero que se puede serializar, es decir tratarlo como string. Por lo tanto un fichero binario **no** es serializable.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev ¿Conoces alguna página, vídeo, pdf... donde se explique a fondo?

Comment: No. Pero estoy hablando de ficheros, no de objetos. La serialziación en java es algo diferente. Solo como ejemplo - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el concepto es ***fichero** serializable*? Porque no tiene mucho sentido; todos los ficheros por definición están ya "serializados" (se pueden representar y reconstruir como una cadena de bytes). Y por supuesto, la interfaz *Serializable* se aplica a **objetos**, no a "ficheros"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que un programa java pueda convertir un objeto en un montón de **bytes** y pueda luego recuperarlo, el objeto necesita ser **Serializable**. Al poder convertir el objeto a bytes, ese objeto se puede *enviar a través de red*, g*uardarlo en un fichero*, y después reconstruirlo al otra lado de la red, leerlo del fichero,....

Para que un objeto sea serializable basta con que implemente la interfaz **Serializable**. Como la interfaz Serializable no tiene métodos, es muy sencillo implementarla, basta con un implements Serializable y nada más. Por ejemplo, la clase Datos siguiente es Serializable y java sabe perfectamente enviarla o recibirla por red, a través de socket o de rmi. También java sabe escribirla en un fichero o reconstruirla a partir del fichero.

```
public class Datos implements Serializable
{
   public int a;
   public String b;
   public char c;
}
```

Si dentro de la clase hay atributos que son otras clases, éstos a su vez también deben ser Serializable. Con los tipos de java (String, Integer, etc.) no hay problema porque lo son. Si ponemos como atributos nuestras propias clases, éstas a su vez deben implementar Serializable. Por ejemplo

```
/* Esta clase es Serializable porque implementa Serializable y todos sus
*  campos son Serializable, incluido "Datos f;"
*/
public class DatoGordo implements Serializable
{
    public int d;
    public Integer e;
    Datos f;
}
```

No te explico como guardar o leer archivos porque no lo aclaraste en la pregunta creo que con esta explicacion bastante sencilla y simple te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Sí, solo tenía la duda de qué hacía exactamente Serializable. Guardar y leer archivos ya sé más o menos, gracias!